# Determine whether a sequence $a_{n} = \frac{ \sin^2{n}}{ \sqrt{n}}$ is convergent or divergent and find its limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $ \{ a_{n} \}$ be a sequence given by $$ a_{n} = \frac{ \sin^2 (n)}{ \sqrt{n} } $$ Determine whether $ \{ a_{n} \}$ is convergent or divergent and if it's convergent, find $$ \lim_{ n \to \infty } a_{n}$$ Usually, what's the approach we use for series like this? I'm particularly curious about the sine function.

Comment: $0\le \sin^2 n\le1$

Comment: Do you mean _sequence_ or _series_? You ask 'is the sequence convergent?' but say 'given an infinite series'; these are two very different things.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki oh yeah, sorry, it's edited now

Comment: For $a_{n} = (-1)^n \frac{ \sin^2{n}}{ \sqrt{n}}$ series is converge. And $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds $$ 0 \leq \sin^2 (n) \leq 1,$$ hence $$ 0 \leq \frac{ \sin^2 (n) }{ \sqrt{n} } \leq \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n}} $$ so by the pinching theorem $$ \frac{ \sin^2 (n) }{ \sqrt{n} } \to 0, \ n \to \infty$$ because $ \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n}} \to 0, \ n \to \infty$.